# Aurelia call function on component from button

Tags: aurelia

If I have a custom component with it's own function.

```
export class ModalWindow {
  public modalelement: HTMLElement; 

  show() {
    $(this.modalelement).modal('show');
  }
}
```

Is there a way of exposing `show()` for other elements (like a button on my page) to call?

```
<modal-window></modal-window>
<button click.delegate="modal-window.show()">Show modal</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Flipping heck, spent ages trying to work this out and finally decided to post here.
5 minutes later, I work it out:

```
<modal-window view-model.ref="addmodal"></modal-window>
<button click.delegate="addmodal.show()">Show modal</button>
```

I am happy to hear of any better options if you can think of anything?

Comment: I think what you got is good, as it seems bindable is not an option :+1: